# String Replacement with multi-return RegEx ('g') + Switch in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, str-replace

I am working on this assignment on free code camp, and for some reason, which I can't seem to figure out, I am not getting the correct output. My debug logs seem to occur as expected, but it seems as though I'm missing something. I have used [`string.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) before with an anonymous function, and it worked fine. In this case, I don't seem to be actually replacing my matches on the string as expected, and I imagine it has something to do with using the [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for matches.

I can't figure out how to make this go. Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```js
function convertHTML(str) {
  var re = new RegExp('[$\"\'\<\>&]', 'g');
  str.replace(re, function (match) {
    console.log("match");
    console.log(match);
    switch (match) {
      case "&":
        return "&amp;";
      case "$":
        return "&dollar;";
      case '"':
        return "&quot;";
      case "'":
        return "&apos;";
      case "<":
        return "&lt;";
      case ">":
        return "&gt;";
    }
    console.log("oops");
  });
  console.log(str);
  return str;
}

convertHTML("Dolce & Gabbana");
convertHTML("Hamburgers < Pizza < Tacos");
convertHTML("Sixty > twelve");
convertHTML('Stuff in "quotation marks"');
convertHTML("Shindler's List");
convertHTML("<>");
```

Comment: You are forgetting to assign, `replace` is not *in-place* so change to:  `str = str.replace(re, function (match) {`

Answer (score 1):

[String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) does not change the *String* object it is called on. It simply returns a new string.

```
...
// to change/overwrite the initial string
str = str.replace(re, function (match) {
...
});
```